# Swift_TransportException Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. ]

Tags: laravel, email, smtp

Here is route file
**web.php**

```
Route::post('/share-with-me/send', 'ShareWithMeController@send')->name('share-with-me-send');
```

here is my env file
**.env**

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=*****
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=****
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Here is the controller with send function
**ShareWithMeController.php**

```
function send(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [

            'message' =>  'required'
        ]);

        $data = array(
            'name'      =>  $request->name,
            'email'      =>  $request->email,
            'message'   =>   $request->message
        );

        Mail::to('test@gmail.com')->send(new SendMail($data));
        return back()->with('success', 'Thanks for Informing! Your Identity is Hidden.');

    }
```

Here is the Build function
**Sendmail.php**

```
public function build()
    {

        return $this->from('himel@viserx.com')->subject('Employee Feedback')->view('feedback')->with('data', $this->data);
    }
```

I am facing that error while sending email.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your mail driver is set to smtp, email provider supports TLS encryption & the port is 465.